# Downloading a provisioning profile for text-to-speech api support

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm using xCode trying to download my 'provisioning profile' for production level support from an ios text to speech service.

I exported the app and was able to export my developer account, but I can't seem to just open the contents and access the provisional profile.

When i click 'view details' -> 'download all' in the accounts page nothing happens...

Anyone have any idea how I can just download my provisioning profile?

Answer (score 1):

You need to log in to the members area of developer.apple.com and find the "Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles" section. On the left will be sections for certificates, identifiers, devices, and profiles. You want Provisioning Profiles. The last entry under Provisioning Profiles is "Distribution." Click on that and you should see a list of the distribution provisioning profiles available under your account. If you select one it should show you a details page with an option to download that profile.